# Is there a way to get file from ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Tags: android, file, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get file from google drive using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.
When I clicked the file, then the results are:

```
uri.getPath() : "/document/acc=1;doc=encoded=K45Kn19bK1yXpNssYJAhfwJ/4hgc5VmQJk2FWtVNoeM+c1vHUO4H"

uri.toString():"content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3DK45Kn19bK1yXpNssYJAhfwJ%2F4hgc5VmQJk2FWtVNoeM%2Bc1vHUO4H"

File recoveryFIle = new File(uri.toString());
file size : 0
```

How can I get the real file? I select the file from Google Drive.

```
getfile
                Intent recovery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                recovery.setType("*/*");
                recovery.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Savelocation_Backup");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(recovery, "Share File"),3002);
```

```
result
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Log.d("TAG",uri.getPath()+"");
                Log.d("TAG",uri.toString());
                File recoveryFIle = new File(uri.toString());
                Log.d("TAG",recoveryFIle.length()+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Impossible.

Stop trying.

Moreover you need not what you call a file.